# Does it exist MIME Headers Decoder (RFC 2047) for ruby?

Tags: ruby, mime

I have encoded header (part for example: =?UTF-8?B?ZXIgQXNzZXJ0aW9uIElzc3Vlcjwvc2FtbDpJc3N1ZQ==?= =?UTF-8?B?cj48ZHNpZzpTaWduYXR1cmUgeG1sbnM6ZHNpZz0iaA==?=)

How can i decode it to normal view with ruby? (er Assertion Issuer

Base64.decode64 - does not work

Comment: Thank you, it is strange that I could not find the answer, although I was looking

Comment: I've added the "RFC 2047" part to the other question's title. Maybe you couldn't find it because it was missing.